# How to Intent.ACTION_SEND with correct file name?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, share

I need to share audio (music) file, but when I use following code, I got file with different name, which is not good. Because it is music file, I need to keep all atributes, like artist, title and name of file. Is there any way how to do it?

```
        final String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Music/music.mp3";
        final Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentShareFile.setType("audio/*");
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile,"Share"));
```

I am using WhatsApp for testing.

Comment: Where is `filePath` coming from? Does it have the correct filename? If it does, then WhatsApp would appear to have changed the name that it used, and I doubt that there is anything you can do about that.

Comment: Can you please post how the file path is taken / framed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 packageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("topPackageName");
 String audioName = arrAudio.get(position).getAudioFileName();
                File audioFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EmoticApp/AudioFile/" + audioName);

                Uri audioUri = Uri.fromFile(audioFile);
                Intent audioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                audioIntent.setType("audio/*");
                audioIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audioUri);
                audioIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                startActivity(audioIntent);
```