# Intent Share Chooser not showing correct names

Tags: android

I first created a new pdf file using:

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
            values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents");

            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
            document.writeTo(fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            values.clear();
            resolver.update(uri, values, null, null);
```

Now I pass this "uri" to different activity where I choose Intent.Action_Send to share pdf file to say whatsapp using:

```
Intent intentShareFile;
intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);  
intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"), FINISH_SHARING);
```

This open the intent chooser window with multiple apps, whatsapp, facebook, but shows the number "39913" from the uri "content://media/external/file/39913" instead of file name. I expect to show my file name here "New.pdf". Can you please solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: The URI is not the same as the FilePath, that's been like that since I remember, there are some ways to get the path from uri. But try using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43185074/15298643) to send your pdf; as a File object

Comment: @javdromero The reference link is also using uri to send the data. See this link                 `audioIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audioUri);`. But he has made that uri from a File object containing the exact path of the audiofile. I do not know the exact path to the pdf file. So any solution to that?

Comment: As I suggested previously, you could run a test in your app, using `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` for your name, then see what `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` returns. If that returns `39913`, then the problem lies in `MediaStore`. If it returns a real display name, then the problem lies with the other apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(uri).getName()` returns the name of the file "New.pdf". I also tried with `(new File(uri)).getName()` but this returns "39913". Do you have idea about what problem it may be?  Is there any way to show my file name instead of "39913" in the above picture? I have even saw several apps sharing pdfs which shows the name of the file. I wonder how they might be doing it?

Comment: "Yes DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(uri).getName() returns the name of the file "New.pdf"." -- is your problem limited to the share sheet? IOW, do the actual apps that you share the content with have the right name? If so, then your problem probably is that you have to give permission to the share sheet itself: https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/01/07/action_send-share-sheet-clipdata.html

Comment: Yes the apps that I share content with have the file name. I tried all the solutions in the link and changed to `Intent intentShareFile; intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); intentShareFile.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri(null,uri)); intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf"); intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`. But still the problem persists and still the same. Really getting irritated by the problem now.